# AGP 7+ / JDK 11 / release: ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, gradlew, android-r8

As the title says, I'm having some issue on a project since we updated to Java 11 and to AGP 7+.
The issue only happens in release and when we make a retrofit call using okhttp3.MultipartBody :

```
2022-01-18 00:56:23.043 27908-27908/com.test.okhttpissue E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.okhttpissue, PID: 27908
    java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part not present
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76)
        at libcore.reflect.GenericArrayTypeImpl.getGenericComponentType(GenericArrayTypeImpl.java:32)
        at j2.y.j(:362)
        at j2.s$a.j(:812)
        at j2.s$a.g(:626)
        at j2.s$a.f(:325)
        at j2.s$a.b(:206)
        at j2.s.b(:67)
        at j2.v.b(:26)
        at j2.u.c(:202)
        at j2.u$a.invoke(:160)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy2.a(Unknown Source)
        at f1.a.a(:41)
        at com.test.okhttpissue.MainActivity.G(:30)
        at com.test.okhttpissue.MainActivity.F(Unknown Source:0)
        at f1.b.onClick(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7259)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7236)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27896)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:65)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76) 
        at libcore.reflect.GenericArrayTypeImpl.getGenericComponentType(GenericArrayTypeImpl.java:32) 
        at j2.y.j(:362) 
        at j2.s$a.j(:812) 
        at j2.s$a.g(:626) 
        at j2.s$a.f(:325) 
        at j2.s$a.b(:206) 
        at j2.s.b(:67) 
        at j2.v.b(:26) 
        at j2.u.c(:202) 
        at j2.u$a.invoke(:160) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006) 
        at $Proxy2.a(Unknown Source) 
        at f1.a.a(:41) 
        at com.test.okhttpissue.MainActivity.G(:30) 
        at com.test.okhttpissue.MainActivity.F(Unknown Source:0) 
        at f1.b.onClick(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7259) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7236) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27896) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.okhttpissue-pBclZ8Dcl_TuV_j7iAp7oA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.okhttpissue-pBclZ8Dcl_TuV_j7iAp7oA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:65) 
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76) 
        at libcore.reflect.GenericArrayTypeImpl.getGenericComponentType(GenericArrayTypeImpl.java:32) 
        at j2.y.j(:362) 
        at j2.s$a.j(:812) 
        at j2.s$a.g(:626) 
        at j2.s$a.f(:325) 
        at j2.s$a.b(:206) 
        at j2.s.b(:67) 
        at j2.v.b(:26) 
        at j2.u.c(:202) 
        at j2.u$a.invoke(:160) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006) 
        at $Proxy2.a(Unknown Source) 
        at f1.a.a(:41) 
        at com.test.okhttpissue.MainActivity.G(:30) 
        at com.test.okhttpissue.MainActivity.F(Unknown Source:0) 
        at f1.b.onClick(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7259) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7236) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27896) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935) 
2022-01-18 00:56:23.074 27908-27908/com.test.okhttpissue I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27908 SIG: 9
```

The problem **does not** occur on AGP 4.2.2 / Java 1.8.

I was able to reproduce it in a basic sample app with the following configuration :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.okhttpissue"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.3"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
}
```

And the following snippet :

```
class IssueDemo {

    val testApi: TestApi by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://google.com")
            .client(OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(TestApi::class.java)
    }

    interface TestApi {

        @Multipart
        @POST("test/files")
        fun uploadMultipleFiles(@Part files: Array<MultipartBody.Part?>): Single<String>
    }

    fun execute() {
        val file = File("")
        val requestFile: RequestBody =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file)
        val test = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("nameFormData", file.name, requestFile)
        testApi.uploadMultipleFiles(arrayOf(test))
    }
}
```

I tried many things but so far the only thing that seems to fix it is to add a proguard rule `-keep class okhttp3.MultipartBody` but it doesn't feel right. With AGP 4.2.2 it was already using R8 and the proguard rules bundled with the library so why would we suddendly need another specific rule just for one class of this library?

**Edit:** It seems that switching from  `Array<MultipartBody.Part?>` to `List<MultipartBody.Part?>`, without touching any proguard rule, solves the issue. Does someone understand what could be happening?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I am running in the same issue and my app has a vast number of retrofit use-cases. Finding, checking and adding rule for each and every one of those is not feasible at the moment. If you were able to find a general solution or any issue tracker for this then that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Possible that R8 can't detect the class being used as it may be invoked by reflection. If that is the case, you have to add explicit keep rule in proguard-project.txt.

Comment: It indeed works with the rule `-keep class okhttp3.MultipartBody` but that was not necessary when using AGP 4.2.2, which also uses R8. And this class being obfuscated was not causing any issue before.